# Awk command to find the most common word in a file?

Tags: awk, file-search

Lets say i have a file that is simply a list full of dates and names, And i need to look for the "team name" that is repeated most in that list? Player name is located at position $1 and team position $2.

i am trying to use awk? *So, How to say "go through position 2 on the table and check what word is most used? "* simple as that, i see people using uniq -c , but in my classe we haven't talked about it. Thank you

Here is a file example:

```
Player | team 
DiMaria Benfica
Otamendi Benfica
Robertocarlos Madrid
JoaoFelix Benfica
Cristiano Sporting
Maldini Milan
```

How do i code this to put out that Benfica is the team that shows more ?
Thank you.

Comment: Please, post an example and a desired output

Comment: done, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done on many ways. Here is one of them:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=1} END {max=0;for( i in a) {if(a[i]>max) {b=i; max=a[i]}}; print b, max }' <input file>
```

First it create associative array `a` where it organise counter. Then it loop thru the elements of array and search for maximum value. Store counter in `max` and name in `b`

For sure there is shorter script, but for me this is more readable and easy for understand :)